# Aerospike: Migrating from Python client to Go client

Tags: aerospike

I was using Aerospike since 3.4 and Python client 1.0.31.
Currently upgraded to Aerospike 3.6.3  and Python client 1.0.50.

Since Python client doesn't have Async writes feature, I am planning to go with Golang. Also read that Go fits well with Aerospike (http://www.aerospike.com/blog/go-aerospike-a-perfect-match/)

I would like to know what are the consequence I will face on changing the client and how to handle them.

One of the issue I see is serialization. As I was using python client since Aerospike 3.4, How to handle older serialized data like float values. I Need not worry on new data as recent releases support floats natively.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Well, "Python client doesn't have Async" needs to come with a big *yet*. The C client 4.0.0 provides async operations. The current work being done in the Python client is compatibility with Python >= 3.4. Async is something that is planned.

The main thing to consider when moving from one language client to another, or when combining different SDKs is how to handle 'unsupported' types. You'll have to review your data for where it will contain serialized data in as_bytes, encoded as AS_BYTES_PYTHON. See the 'Serialization' section in the [Python API doc](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/aerospike.html). You want to come up with a common custom serialization scheme to allow your Go client to read that data.

Comment: Thanks for your useful reply.  I think the recent aerospike release supports float/double values natively.  If I do my own de-serialization, then I may missing out the core feature.  I am thinking how can I migrage these existing floats re-written with Aerospike compatible values so that I need not change anything on Go client side if I am migrating from python client.  Any thoughts?

Comment: The serialization/deserialization only applies to the unsupported types, so a float would not be touched by it. It's there to handle things like Boolean. Other than the common data issue there are no big changes. Go is a very different language, obviously, and conceptually you want to have your one client that handles all the requests on your behalf, but that's similar to how you'd use the Python client in most Python frameworks.

Comment: @ Ronen, Thanks Ronen.  The only need I am in urge to move to Go is, I am not able to do async writes.

Comment: Well, in about a week you'll be able to use a Python 3 compatible client that can do multi-threaded work. You can plug this into an async framework like gevent. Actual multi-threaded functionality will follow that. But you need to consider your own timing.